# Modular arithmetic word problem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

We are buying a total of 12 fruits (apples and bananas) for 132 dollars.
If the apples are 3 dollars more expensive than the bananas, and we bought more apples than bananas, how many bananas we bought?

Or in other words:

- Let $a=$ Apple price
- Let $b=$ Banana price
- Let $x=$ Apples bought
- Let $y=$ Bananas bought

We know that:

$$x+y=12$$

$$x>y$$

$$a=b+3$$

$$xa+yb=132$$

therefore
$$x(b+3) + yb=132$$

which yields $x=44-4b$ or $y=4b-32$

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to solve a system of linear equations, but as there are more variables than equations i see it can't be done that way.
I don't know how to implement the modular arithmetic (most probably congruence because that's what we are studying right now) so i got stuck.

Comment: Please write it up for us, we read that easier than text:)
And, I guess you also need the implicit information that we are looking for *integer* numbers.

Comment: Is this more helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let be $\,x=$ the number of apples, $\,a=$ price of each apple, $\,y=$number of bananas, $\,b=$ price of each banana, then you have the equations

$$x+y=12\Longleftrightarrow x = 12-y\;\;,\;\;\;ax+by=132\;\;,\;\;\;a=b+3\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$(b+3)(12-y)+by=132\Longleftrightarrow 4b-y=32$$

Do a little more algebra, take into account that $\,y>x\,$ and they both are integers...and what is a clear divisor of $\,y\,$?

Comment: That's as far as i got, i am stuck right there.

Comment: Ok, can you tell what a clear divisor of $\,y\,$ is?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know.

Comment: $\,y=4b-32\,$ , so if the right side is divisible by $\,4\,$ ...

Comment: Well the divisor of y has to be 4 as well then?

Comment: And if y is divisible by 4 and x+y=12 and x>y , then y=4 meaning x=8 ?

Comment: Exactly Nikola ! Of course, the second non-realistic possibility is $\,y=0\,\,,\,\,x=12\,$

Comment: I'd never get it right without your guidance, thanks a lot man! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using all the former substitutions we have
x=12-y,x>y,,, 12-yy or y>6
Both apples and bananas were bought, so y is between 1 and 5
from earlier solutions we have that y=4b-32
therefore y is divisible by 4
from information in the third line we conclude that
y=4  So there are 4 bananas bought.